# Grub issue in 12.04: "Booting in blind mode."

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, grub-efi

I just turned on my PC where I'm dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 8 and I had the following message at startup:

```
Invalid video mode 'text'
Booting in blind mode
```

Fortunately for me the laptop booted up fine anyways in **blind mode** and I was able to log in, however I've googled around and it turns out that this is an issue with Grub and it can be more serious in some cases.

Any idea on how to fix/correct this in a safe manner? Or what could I do to check that my Grub doesn't have any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, apparently it has something to do with having **Legacy Grub** rather than **Grub 2**. Not sure whether is was UEFi that wasn't playing nice with it, but updating Grub to Grub2 using the following steps solved this issue and my laptop boots normally without the message:

1. Open a terminal and run: `sudo apt-get install grub-pc`
2. Accept when a pop-up window asks whether to chainload to Grub2 or not:

   > [image]
3. I accepted adding all the boot menu entries seeing as my system booted correctly before

   > > [image]
4. Select the correct drive where to install Grub 2. Selected by using the <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> and <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to highlight the drives to install it on, tabbing to the `<OK>` before pressing enter once done.

> > [image]
> >     5. Then reboot by using `sudo reboot`. On reboot you are queried whether to chainload or not:
> >
> > > > [image]

Once I checked that all my Grub entries worked correctly in Grub2 by rebooting to test each of them I upgraded Grub to Grub2 using `sudo upgrade-from-grub-legacy` in a terminal window.

I'm not sure if this is just a workaround but at least my problem seems to be solved for the time being.

*Sources of information/screenshots:*

- [Ubuntu Community Site on upgrading to Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading)
- [UnixNewbie Explanations on how to upgrade to Grub2](http://www.unixnewbie.org/how-to-easily-upgrade-grub-2/)

Comment: I have messed up things by doing this... I am unable to boot without a boot repair disk. I get an error: /grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod not found. Can you also write a procedure to undo things... That is going back to the legacy grub from the grub2 please.